# importing static text file into angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, module, text-files

I am trying to read a static Markdown text file in an angular 6 app project folder to serve project documentation of the app.

The typescript documentation at [https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript...wildcard-character-in-module-names](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#wildcard-character-in-module-names) describes a method for importing text files.  There is not a lot of information described there to get wrong, but it is not working in my Angular app.

The error message I am seeing from most of the things I have tried is about the import statement not being able to find the module.

One of the more frustrating error messages has text from the start of the text file, so the angular module loader was able to load the file, saying:

> Module parse failed: Assigning to rvalue (3:10) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I am kinda new at angular and typescript, but it seems like the described wildcard module name text import feature is just not working.  Has anyone else has success with that typescript feature?

Comment: heh, thanks downvote, could have known better to try to serve md file as site doc without a phd in angular

Comment: This isn't a typescript problem. Looks looks to me like you don't have a (webpack?) loader for the file you are trying to import.

Comment: @Gerrit0, I think you could be right, do you have any hints on info about maybe ng server text file loaders?